# Why were generics used in this context?

Tags: c#, generics, object, serialization, methods

```
public static string JsonSerializer<T>(T t)
{
    DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    ser.WriteObject(ms, t);
    string jsonString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
    ms.Close();
    return json;
}
```

Above is your typical json helper method. What is the relevance of `<T>`  and the relevance of passing the parameter as type T?

Given the fact that all objects inherit from `object`, I would expect this method signature to read:

```
public static string JsonSerializer(object t)...
```

I appreciate it's probably a bad style of questioning to ask the SO community why somebody else's code reads in a certain way but this is a pretty standard helper method found in many articles and tutorials so I'm expecting the approach to be that of an accepted one.

Comment: Probably for `typeof(T)`? Which is a way to get the declaring type of the variable.

Comment: But I was under the impression object.GetType() could take the place of this? Thanks for reply.

Comment: Yes, but `typeof(T)` is resolved at compile time, whereas `GetType()` is resolved at runtime.

Comment: @CédricBignon So what?

Comment: @delnan So, it's slightly faster. Nothing else. I don't believe it makes any difference in this case.

Answer (score 4):

This is just so you don't have to use `GetType()` to get the type of `T` for the `DataContractJsonSerializer`. It also stops boxing for value types.

Comment: But I was under the impression object.GetType() could take the place of this? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Make sure you understand the second part of the answer as well. You can use the generic method with a value type like `int` without boxing it into an object.

Comment: @Alden - it's the 2nd part of the answer I'm now struggling to understand. Am I right in saying if you passed an int as t in this scenario and it was expecting an object it would box the int (value type) as an object (reference) and then pass this 'boxed' object to the WriteObject method when it could've just been passed as int 'directly'? Thanks again for all replies. Really helpful so far.

Comment: In this case, it will end up getting boxed anyway, because WriteObject takes an object as the second parameter. So I guess the only optimization is the compile time typeof(). However in general, you can pass a value type as a generic parameter without it being boxed.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is optimization. When some function is generic, compiler will generate as many instances of this function as many different types are used in the calls. This means that each specific instantiation will know its exact type and enable optimizations that are specific to the type of the argument, like: 32 bit arithmetic instead of 64 bits, avoid unnecessary boxing, call non virtual methods, etc.

In this particular case of `JsonSerializer<T>(T t)` the gain might be not so big. In general, especially when the function is called millions in times the gain can be well worth of this complication in the signature.

Comment: In this specific case? I don't see any virtual method called from `t` and there will be boxing in all cases because of `ser.WriteObject(Stream, object)`.

Comment: Thanks very much mate, appreciate the answer.